# make: *** [build-java] Error 1 building java-gnome 4.1.2 from source

Tags: compilation, makefile

I'm trying to build java-gnome 4.1.2 from source (http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/java-gnome/4.1/) using the instructions given here: http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/README.html.

The './configure' command works fine and suggests there are no dependency issues but 'make' gives me the following output:

```
build/faster
GCC     generated/bindings/org/gnome/unique/UniqueApp.c
/usr/bin/gcc-4.6  -g -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include -                    I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include/linux -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast -Wno-pointer-to-int-    cast  -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfatal-errors -Isrc/jni -Itmp/include -      pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gtksourceview-3.0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/librsvg-2.0 -I/usr/include/enchant -o tmp/objects/org/gnome/unique/UniqueApp.o -c     generated/bindings/org/gnome/unique/UniqueApp.c
generated/bindings/org/gnome/unique/UniqueApp.c:44:27: fatal error: unique/unique.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build-java] Error 1
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc` was unable to find `unique/unique.h` in the provided include paths.  Each path after the `-I` will be added to the set of include paths.  Find the location of `unique/unique.h` and make certain that path is on the `gcc` command line.

Comment: Hmm I have a unique folder in the right place but there is no unique.h file anywhere at all (as far as I can see there are no .h files of any kind only .c and .java) I'm assuming this is a file that should have been generated not something I should have from some dependency or other? How would I go about finding out why I don't have this file?

Comment: It looks like unique is another library that you will need to get setup.

https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-power-manager/issues/5

https://live.gnome.org/LibUnique

You may also just be able to do something like: `sudo apt-get install libunique-3.0-0`.  It appears that quantal has packages for java-gnome already as well.  Consider using them?

Comment: apt-get install tells me I already have the newest version installed. It was one of the dependencies. I'm still using Precise so I hadn't considered using quantal packages - is that an option?

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=unique.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=quantal&arch=any

looks like you need the -dev package.  pick the version (1.0 or 3.0) that you need

Comment: Ah sorry obtuse. I see usr/include/unique-3.0 needs to be added to the set of include paths - is that in the make file or somewhere else?

Comment: sure thing.  the package contents search i linked to is particularly useful.  don't know what i file is?  where to get it?  it doesn't always have the answer but it often helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after googling for a while and coming up blank, I ended up moving "unique" dir from "unique-3.0" dir to /usr/include. Everything worked after